# I need help making a progress bar dissapear

Tags: html

now that I got a progress bar, I need to know how to make the bar vanish after it's finished loading. If possible, I want it to vanish and then redirect to another website. Thanks for all of the help guys.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Initializing...</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  .progress-label {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
      progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

    progressbar.progressbar({
      value: false,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
      },
      complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
      }
    });

    function progress() {
      var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

      progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );

      if ( val < 99 ) {
        setTimeout( progress, 100 );
      }
    }

    setTimeout( progress, 3000 );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Initializing...</div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe a fiddle? Try [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
complete: function() {
    this.hide();    
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```